# ggplot2 legend display

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add a legend to a overlay of polygons with multiple point datasets, however I am not able to add a legend. This is similar to what I have

1 shapefile with polygons & 1 dbf file with point coordinates

```
> polygon.file.fortify<-fortify.SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(polygon1,region="UG")

> head(polygon.file.fortify)
      long      lat order  hole piece    group     id
1 35.02638 1.925453     1 FALSE     1 Uganda.1 Uganda
2 35.02480 1.912348     2 FALSE     1 Uganda.1 Uganda
3 35.01902 1.884518     3 FALSE     1 Uganda.1 Uganda
4 35.01396 1.847906     4 FALSE     1 Uganda.1 Uganda
5 35.01143 1.827074     5 FALSE     1 Uganda.1 Uganda
6 35.00699 1.796143     6 FALSE     1 Uganda.1 Uganda

> point.file
      UG ORIG_FID coords_x1 coords_x2
1 Uganda        0  32.29987  1.332974
```

The **ggplot2** code I have is similar to this:

```
qplot(main="Uganda",ylab="Latitude",xlab="Longitude") +
    geom_polygon(data=polygon.fortify, aes(x = long, y=lat, group = NULL), 
                 ylab="Latitude",xlab="Longitude",colour = "black", fill = NA) +
    geom_point(data=point.file, aes(x=point.file$coords_x1,y=point.file$coords_x2, group=NULL),
               colour="red",shape=24,size=3,fill="blue")
```

From what I've seen a way to solve the legend problem is to add the colour inside `aes()`, but I still have some problems with the legend:

[image: graphics]

```
qplot(main="Uganda",ylab="Latitude",xlab="Longitude") +
    geom_polygon(data=polygon.file.fortify, aes(x = long, y=lat, group = NULL,colour = "black"), 
                 ylab="Latitude",xlab="Longitude", fill = NA) +
    geom_point(data=point.file, aes(x=point.file$coords_x1,y=point.file$coords_x2, group=NULL,colour="red"),
               shape=24,size=3,fill="blue") + 
    scale_colour_manual(values=c("black","red"))
```

I don't know where the problem is and also if there is a way to associate the legend to the shape instead of colour, since I have a list of different files to plot (all points) where I use different shape types.

Some of the points are very close to each others, that is why I am using shapes with a fill colour.

Comment: I suspect that you are confused about some basic ggplot2 functionality. It looks like you're trying to plot one point at a time, which simply isn't how one is supposed to do things in ggplot. Typically, you'd have a data frame with _all_ the points, including a column that identifies groups that you can map to `colour` in `aes` and then the legend will be created automatically.

Comment: and how would I solve the problem of adding the polygon reference to the legend? until now i have only been using data frames, but now I would like to add a polygon feature and I am not sure how I can add this to a legend.

Comment: If it's just one (or 2-3) polygons you're adding, it would probably make more sense to label them with annotations in the graph itself.